# How can i get order_total without taxes and shipping cost ? On woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, affiliate

i want put an pixel for tracking my orders for affiliate.

I must get my total order after discount, so without Tax and Shipping cost.

I've make something like this but it's display 0 .

```
<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_total_ex_tax(); ?>
```

It's maybe because it's display currency symbol.

Comment: Why isn't `0` an acceptable return value? It sounds like the order total is actually `0`, after discounts, and before shipping and taxes.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, because that can matter the amount of my order my return value is always 0. So It is a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

This it the cart total without tax and shipping.

```
$cart_value = number_format( (float) $order->get_total() - $order->get_total_tax() - $order->get_total_shipping() - $order->get_shipping_tax(), wc_get_price_decimals(), '.', '' );
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks

Comment: $order->get_total_shipping() is deprecated since woocommerce 3.0.0, use $order->get_shipping_total() instead

Answer (score 5):

Vdadmax's answer is *almost* correct. If tax is applied on shipping, then it's deducted twice in his case (the total shipping cost including tax is deducted and after that, shipping sales tax is deducted again), leaving you with a final total that is too low.

This gives you the correct total with all sales tax and shipping deducted:

```
$cart_value = number_format( (float) $order->get_total() - $order->get_total_tax() - $order->get_total_shipping(), wc_get_price_decimals(), '.', '' );
```

I can't comment yet, hence the reason why I am adding this as an answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried?

```
$cart_value = $order->get_total_tax() - $order->get_total();
```

Comment: Will end in a negative number, not good.

Answer (score 1):

This helps me to get the total amount without tax.

```
WC()->cart->subtotal_ex_tax();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get_woocommerce_totals()['cart_subtotal']['value']
```